# Sending information cross-domain without touching server-side

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

This is a research question I've been hitting my head on for a while now. I'm not sure if it's possible but it seems like it should be.

How do I make `var token` that was defined in `them.com`'s javascript to be visible to `us.com`'s javascript WITHOUT sending information to any of the two servers?

The goal is to save information in the browser to be accessible cross-domain? `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` are domain-locked. And `set-cookie` make it visible to the server... So I cannot use those.

Comment: You can install a extension(plugin) browser that can set/get any variables accessible cross-domain

Comment: Silly question, but are you even counting query strings (`GET`) as sending information to a server? That'd be the most basic way of doing this I can think of. Cross-domain cookies are possible too but you'd need to allow access via CORS.

Comment: GET cannot be used either. As the URL is stored on the server. Extension's are possible. But I'm looking for a native way.

Answer (score 0):

You could give `CORS Anywhere` a shot. 
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

> CORS Anywhere is a NodeJS proxy which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.

Basically, you can prefix the request URL with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`.

For example:

```
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://your-req-url.com/some-endpoint')
```

You can also host it yourself. Further reading: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/